# How do we pass Chakra RangeSlider values into Formik?

Tags: onchange, formik, chakra-ui, rangeslider

I am trying to pass data into a sign up form with chakra range slider using Formik. I cannot get the changed values passed into my handleSignUp() function.  They are always just showing the initial priceRange values.

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        priceRange: [500, 1200],
      }}
      onSubmit={(values: any) => handleSignUp(values)}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required(),
        email: Yup.string().required().email(),
        password: Yup.string().required().min(6),
        priceRange: Yup.array().required(),
      })}
    >
      {({
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        dirty,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit,
        handleReset,
      }) => {
        return (
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <VStack border="1px" borderColor="gray.200" p="2em">
              <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.email && !!touched.email}>
                <FormLabel htmlFor="name">Name</FormLabel>
                <Input
                  id="name"
                  type="name"
                  value={values.name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
                <FormLabel htmlFor="email">Email</FormLabel>
                <Input
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
                <FormLabel pt="1em" htmlFor="password">
                  Password
                </FormLabel>
                <Input
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
                <FormLabel pt="1em" htmlFor="price range">
                  Preferred Price Range
                </FormLabel>
                <Field
                  name="priceRange"
                  as={RangeSliderElement}
                  title="Preferred Price Range"
                  min={100}
                  defaultMin={500}
                  defaultMax={1000}
                  max={1500}
                  step={50}
                />
                <FormErrorMessage>{errors.email}</FormErrorMessage>
              </FormControl>
              <Button
                mt="2em"
                type="submit"
                isDisabled={isSubmitting}
                colorScheme="purple"
                w="100%"
              >
                Sign Up {'>>'}
              </Button>
            </VStack>
            <HStack w="100%" py="1rem" justifyContent="center">
              <Text>Already on the list? </Text>
              <Button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  setloginNotSignUp(true);
                }}
                isDisabled={isSubmitting}
                variant="ghost"
              >
                Sign In
              </Button>
            </HStack>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
```

My range slider looks like this:

```
const [limit, setLimit] = useState<Array<any>>([defaultMin, defaultMax]);
  const onChangeLimit = (val: any) => {
    setLimit(val);
  };
  return (
    <RangeSlider
      name={name}
      defaultValue={[defaultMin, defaultMax]}
      colorScheme="blue"
      size="lg"
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step={step}
      onChangeEnd={onChangeLimit}
    >
      <RangeSliderTrack
        height="10px"
        borderRadius="5px"
        border="1px solid #1F2023"
        bg="#FFFFFF"
      >
        <RangeSliderFilledTrack />
      </RangeSliderTrack>
      <Tooltip
        label={formatPrice(limit[0])}
        bg="white"
        border="1px solid gray"
        color="black"
        placement="bottom"
        pl={2}
        pr={2}
        isOpen
      >
        <RangeSliderThumb
          index={0}
          w="25px"
          h="25px"
          borderColor="gray"
          border="1px solid"
          borderRadius="5px"
          sx={{
            ':focus': {
              boxShadow: '0 0 3px #fff',
            },
          }}
        >
          <FaGripLinesVertical color="gray" />
        </RangeSliderThumb>
      </Tooltip>
      <Tooltip
        label={formatPrice(limit[1])}
        bg="white"
        border="1px solid gray"
        color="black"
        placement="bottom"
        pl={3}
        pr={3}
        isOpen
      >
        <RangeSliderThumb
          index={1}
          w="25px"
          h="25px"
          borderColor="gray"
          border="1px solid"
          borderRadius="5px"
          sx={{
            ':focus': {
              boxShadow: '0 0 3px #fff',
            },
          }}
        >
          {' '}
          <FaGripLinesVertical color="gray" />
        </RangeSliderThumb>
      </Tooltip>
    </RangeSlider>
  );
```

I tried passing the handleChange function into the rangeslider onChange prop but either it isn't being passed properly or I dont know how to access it. I thought that formik automatically passes values into the Field component, but I can't see where to adjust the values onChange...?

Answer (score 0):

Example that worked for me:

```
                    <Field name='price'>
                    {({field, form}) => (
                        <>
                            <Text color={'gray.500'} size="sm">
                                £{field?.value[0]} - £{field?.value[1]}
                            </Text>

                            <FormControl display='flex' alignItems='center'>
                                <RangeSlider {...field} name={'price'}
                                             defaultValue={[field?.value[0], field?.value[1]]} onChange={(val) =>
                                    form.setFieldValue(field.name, val)
                                }
                                             value={formik.values.price}>
                                    <RangeSliderTrack bg='red.100'>
                                        <RangeSliderFilledTrack bg='tomato'/>
                                    </RangeSliderTrack>
                                    <RangeSliderThumb boxSize={6} index={0}>
                                        <Box color='tomato' as={MdGraphicEq}/>
                                    </RangeSliderThumb>
                                    <RangeSliderThumb boxSize={6} index={1}>
                                        <Box color='tomato' as={MdGraphicEq}/>
                                    </RangeSliderThumb>
                                </RangeSlider>
                            </FormControl>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Field>
```

The main trick is to use Chakra  [Field](https://formik.org/docs/api/field)

Comment: Did you forget to finish this post?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it :-

1. If you are wrapping the element in another component(this is your case).
   In this case, you pass the field props to the element and using useField()
   hook you can get setValue() in the helpers. you can use value from meta
   and setValue from helpers and you don't have to create a new state to
   maintain that. if you want to give it intialValues just pass that in the
   Formik provider.

```
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props.name);
  
  const { value } = meta;
  const { setValue } = helpers;
  
  const onChangeLimit = (val: any) => {
     setLimit(val);
  };

  //rest of the code from RangeSliderElement
```

2. If you are not wrapping the element in another component. In this case,
   you can cover your element in  (using field as children) and you
   have can have a callback function as a children, in which the render
   props are an object containing field, form and meta. if you console all
   three constituents then you'll find 2 functions, setFieldValue and
   setValue. Using setFieldValue you can set the value of the field (which
   @Wayneio is using), you can set the value for the field and using
   setValue here, you can reset the values for the whole form. That would be
   something like this:

   ```
      <Field name="priceRange">
         {({field, form, meta}) => {
              return (<>
                // code for range slider and in onChange use 
                form.setValues() or form.setFieldValue()
              </>)
          }}
      </Field>
   ```

You can read more about it here :-

https://formik.org/docs/api/field#children

https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldhookconfigvalue